# Python include increment variable within 'for each' loop

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, foreach

I am a Python beginner and I am wondering if is it possible to include an increment variable within for each in Python.
For example, if I have the following for each loop:

```
i = 0
for doc in token_dict.keys():
    docDic[i] = doc
    i = i + 1
```

Can I include in the for each loop instead of defining and increment it every iteration ?

I tried the following:

```
for doc, i in token_dict.keys(), range(len(token_dict.keys())):
   docDic[i] = doc
```

but gave me wrong values.

Comment: in short: `docDic = dict(enumerate(token_dict))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html):

```
for i, doc in enumerate(token_dict):
    docDic[i] = doc
```

(Note also that the `.keys()` is unnecessary for a for loop, since by default iterating over a dictionary operates on the keys).